# Cout does not work on my other turbo c++ complier

Tags: c++, ide, cout, turbo-c++

Hello guys i am beginner on the language c++

i was trying to run this code below on my ide"codeblocks" and it works
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLnPwxZdW4Y (link for the tutorial that following )

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string charactername = "arnold";
    int characterage;
    characterage = 10;
    cout << "Hello my name is" << charactername<< endl;
    cout << "i am " << characterage << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this code does not work on my other compiler running on dosbox ? any ideas why ?

Comment: Turbo C++ is quite outdated regarding the modern c++ standards. For example the header files have a `.h` extension.

Comment: "quite outdated" is a compliment. It's decades out of date at this point.

Comment: Turbo C++ is terribly old. It was created before C++ was standardized. As such, it doesn't even `namespace std`, and it's headers are different. I strongly recommend you to not touch Turbo C++, unless you're forced to.

Comment: As noted Turbo C++ is  old. It's from before C++ was standardized in 1998. You need to find a very old book or a pre-standard tutorial to learn how to program for it. But why would you do that? There are many modern environments that are even free to use (like Code::Blocks).

Comment: _@ArnoldGanapin_ Also note some formal things about your question: _"does not work on my other compiler"_ Isn't a very concise error description. Provide a [mcve] including the exact error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you stop using Turbo C++ as it is a very outdated and a discontinued compiler. However, if you don't have the option of using new compilers (I had the same issue as I studied C++ at school), you will have to make the following changes:

1. `using namespace std;` cannot be used in Turbo C++. You will have to remove that and replace `#include<iostream>` with `#include<iostream.h>`
2. Data-type `string` cannot be used in Turbo C++. You will have to declare a character array instead.
3. You will have to use `#include<stdio.h>` and the function `puts();` to display the character array in case of Turbo C++. Alternatively you can use a loop-statement.

This will be your final code:

```
#include <iostream.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char charactername[] = "arnold";
    int characterage;
    characterage = 10;
    cout << "Hello my name is ";
    puts(charactername);
    cout << "i am " << characterage << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> Note: The `puts();` function automatically puts the cursor on the next line. So you don't need to use `endl;`

Or, if you want to use a loop-statement to display the character array

```
#include <iostream.h> 

int main()
{

    char charactername[] = "arnold";
    int characterage;
    characterage = 10;
    cout << "Hello my name is ";
    int i=0;
    while(charactername[i]!='\0') {
        cout<<charactername[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "i am " << characterage << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> `'\0'` is the last element of the character array. So as long as the loop does not reach the last element, it will print the character array.
>
> `a[] = "arnold";` basically means an array is created like this: `a[0]='a'`, `a[1]='r'`, `a[2]='n'`,.... `a[5]='d'`, `a[6]='\0'`.
>
> Alternatively, if you use `cout << charactername;` instead of the while loop, it will print the whole name. (This is only in the case of a string variable (character array), for an integer array or any other array you will need the while loop)